# Framework interfaces; limited or broad, sugary method synonyms?

Tags: php, interface, fluent-interface

I'm developing a PHP framework; it started off as application-specific, however it has moved into a more agnostic HMVC-style platform which I intend on re-purposing for further projects.

Anyways, while I'm the only developer on the project as it stands, I'm a bit conflicted on my choices of developing the core interfaces.

My main question is (*and I understand this could be deemed slightly subjective*) is it more appropriate to create a strict interface through which client programmers will work, or permit a bit more flexibility. This is best described through an example:

```
class MyDataClass{
    public function getData($key){}
    public function setData($key, $value){}
}
```

This satisfies the requirements (*save for implementation details*) of a simple data registry. The methods are chain-able by returning `$this`, and can contain necessary validation logic. Now the alternative PHP approach:

```
class MyDataClass{
    public function __get($key){}
    public function __set($key, $value){}
}
```

Sure that works too, and provides a clean implementation through the use of PHP's magic. Now, the approach I've seemed to take most often is:

```
class MyDataClass{
    public function getData($key){}
    public function setData($key, $value){}
    public function __get($key){ return $this->getData($key); }
    public function __set($key){ $this->setData($key); }
}
```

Is providing multiple entry points as this example shows a poor choice in design? I always figured it would be a good idea, by centralizing any interaction logic to a single method, but permitting different syntactic choices. I'm now reconsidering this, in favor of a much stricter entry point. A less brief example:

```
class MySuperDataClass implements ArrayAccess{

    // these do the work
    public function getData($key){}
    public function setData($key, $value){}
    public function getChild($name){}
    public function setChild($name, self $child){}

    // these are just sugary synonyms
    public function offsetGet($key){}
    public function offsetSet($key, $value){}
    public function __get($name){}
    public function __set($name, self $child){}

    // ...

}
```

Thoughts?

---

I realized after **OZ_**'s response that I hadn't justified my choice, for understanding the intent of my approach.

For instance, direct method calls (*`getData()` for example*) would be used in controllers, to bind data to a view.

```
$view->setData('foo', 'bar')
     ->setData('alpha', 'beta')
     ->setData('hello', 'world');
```

Whereas magic sugar is used in view generation for readability and brevity.

```
<p><?php echo $view['foo']; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $view['alpha']; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $view['hello']; ?></p>
```

This is how I came to such a convention. I still think it's a nice approach, but as this question alludes, I'm on the fence now in favor of better practices.

---

*Also*: Performance is becoming a concern, as I see the application growing, and these calls are being made iteratively, by using the sugar I'm doubling up my call stack. Sure, micro-optimization I know, but I would think bottleneck potential increases, especially when dealing with PHP magic (*if I've been led to understand correctly, especially `__call()`*) The only way to check is to profile, sure; I've always been a premature optimizer, a habit I'd like to break. Breaking poor design habits is important too.

---

**@jgauffin**; the View classes implement `ArrayAccess`, `Iterator` and `Countable` for this behavior, as well as making use of `__get`/`__set` magic. This is the sugar for the view, whereas the raw methods are called to bind data from the controllers.

```
<?php if($view->canRender('post')): ?>
<div>
<?php foreach($view->post as $post): ?>
    <p><?php echo $post['text']; ?></p>
    <?php if($post->canRender('comments')): ?>
    <div>
    <?php foreach($post->comments as $comment): ?>
        <p><?php echo $comment['text']; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thoughts:

1. While exists at least 1 way, where you can build class without magic methods - use that way, avoid magic methods if you can.
2. If you can't describe class in interface - class was designed wrong.
3. Registry is bad pattern. If you need registry - something is wrong in your design.

[Good book about patterns and design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599098)

Comment: Thanks **OZ_**; Perhaps I should have elaborated a bit. The direct method calls (*`getData` for example*) I use in controllers, whereas sugary methods are available for brevity in view generation. This is the sort of convention that brought me to where I am. Also, the registry pattern was more an example, however I do use it to pass object collection from scope to scope, rather than globalizing the mess, or containing in a wrapper object. I'd have to show an example, but I think it is a fitting use in this case. I'll check out the book, looks perfect; and I'll contractualize my interfaces.

Comment: One problem with magic methods is that they make things a pain when you're refactoring the code or some new person is trying to understand the framework, since you can't just search for a function name to see where it is used. People read code far more than they write it. `$view['foo']` is, conceptually speaking, almost no shorter than `$view->getData('foo')` and you've lost all the benefits of an IDE which can help suggest methods. (Yes, in PHP, they exist.) If you need the brevity in the view-system, consider [view helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html).

Comment: @Darien, and second (and most important) problem in that `__get`, `__set`, `__call`, `__callStatic` can't be properly declared in the Interface class.

Answer (score 1):

I think the direction you are going is great.  The interface would have the methods setData/getData.  Your implementation would implement those methods and for convenience you could implement __set / __get to call the interface methods.

IF another programmer wanted to extend the functionality or add a plugin to your system he would need to make sure his classes implemented your setData/getData method.

Comment: Thanks **Nathan Romano**; That's sort of what I'm going for. The sugar methods are there for use in situations where inlining PHP is necessary and brevity is an asset, such as in view generation.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve with your data class?

I don't see the difference between:

```
yourClass.Set("someNAme", "someValue");
```

and

```
someArray["someName"] = "someValue";
```

Comment: Thanks **jgauffin**; The view objects are designed as repeatable tree nodes. Check my question for a quick example of their use. Also, the view object example is that, an example. The question is intended to be a bit more broad, however the registry/view examples have sorta steamrolled the intent of my question.